# Restoring backup to new environment. Error: Web application not found

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, backup

I am trying to restore a backup of a site collection from my production enviroment to my dev enviroment using the following powershell script:

```
Restore-SPSite http://abd.spdev.<domain> -Path d:\sp2013\abd\abd4jt.bak -hostheaderwebapplication http://SPDEV:80 -Force -DatabaseServer *****-spdev-01\SPDEVDATA -DatabaseName SPDEV_ABD
```

I have created the ABD site collection (with a basic STS#0 teamsite template) and tested it to ensure it is serving data - it is. The SPDEV web app is up and running and working for all my other site collections and the relevant service accounts have dbowner rights to the SPDEV_ABD database on the SPDEVDATA SQL instance.

When I run the script I get this error message:

> Restore-SPSite : The Web application at http://abd.spdev. could
>   not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL
>   should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need
>   to add a new request URL maping to the intended application At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Restore-SPSite -identity http://abd.spdev. -Path d:\sp2013\abd\abd4jt.bak -h ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:SPCmdletRestorSite)
>   [Restore-SPSite], FileNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreSite

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your AAM settings? Most probably your address is not registered in the AAM, could you please share your AAM settings for the web app?

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while back, and it's a little fuzzy, but *I think* your web application has to have the URL "http://abd.spdev", whereas I see you're trying to restore it to the Port 80 web application. Restore it as a site collection to the Port 80; if it's an empty web application, restore it as "" or if there's already something there, try "".

If you want to give it a unique URL, try Alternate Access Binding after restoration.

Edit: This is from a little over a year ago, so I just wanted to emphasize that this is what I *think* was the problem. If another user sees error in this, please let me know :) I like to keep up to date with my SharePoint shenanigans.